# How to copy in Kotlin from assets folder to external or internal storage Android Studio

Tags: kotlin, assets

I founded several code but all in Java... and I tried use ApplicationContext.assets but nothing

Some idea?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function will copy from assets folder and save it in external storage:

```
fun copyAssets(context: Context) {
    val assetManager: AssetManager = context.assets
    var files: Array<String>? = null
    try {
        files = assetManager.list("")

        if (files != null) for (filename in files) {
            var `in`: InputStream? = null
            var out: OutputStream? = null
            try {
                `in` = assetManager.open(filename)
                val outFile = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename)
                out = FileOutputStream(outFile)
                copyFile(`in`, out)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: $filename", e)
            } finally {
                if (`in` != null) {
                    try {
                        `in`.close()
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
                if (out != null) {
                    try {
                        out.close()
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e)
    }

}

@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun copyFile(`in`: InputStream?, out: OutputStream) {
    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    var read: Int? = null
    while (`in`?.read(buffer).also({ read = it!! }) != -1) {
        read?.let { out.write(buffer, 0, it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that it's worked. How to add folder to output file?  thanks again!

Comment: Ok, only need add folder here: val outFile = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "/newFolder/" + filename)